# Reparenting a Window as a Tab in a GTK Notebook

Tags: gtk, gtk#

I'm using Mono with GTK# and am trying to display an existing window as a new tab in a GTK.Notebook.  I'm currently re-parenting the widget to the notebook as follows:

```
MyWindow myWindow = new MyWindow();
myWindow.Children[0].Reparent(myNotebook)
```

Should I be doing this, or is there a better way to re-use an existing window so that you can display it on a tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your way is the best way, there's no way to embed windows into tabs without using horrible hacks like `GtkPlug` (which I'd guess you'd be uninterested in if you're using .NET). Look at the code to `gnome-terminal` for an example of how to do this.